# How to determine if vertical scroll bar has reached the bottom of the web page?

Tags: javascript, window, scrollbar

The same question is answered in jQUery but I'm looking for solution without jQuery.
[How do you know the scroll bar has reached bottom of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060389/how-do-you-know-the-scroll-bar-has-reached-bottom-of-a-page)

I would like to know **how I can determine whether vertical scrollbar has reached the bottom of the web page.**

I am using `Firefox3.6`

I wrote simple Javascript loop to scroll down by 200 pixel and when the scroll bar reached the bottom of the page, I want to stop the loop.

The problem is **scrollHeight() is returning 1989.**

And inside loop `scrollTop` is incremented by 200 per iteration.

```
200 ==> 400 ==> 600 .... 1715
```

And from 1715, it won't increment so this loop continues forever.

Looks like scrollHeight() and scrollTop() is not right way to compare in order to determine the actual position of scrollbar? How can I know when the loop should stop?

**code:**

```
var curWindow = selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow();
var scrollTop = curWindow.document.body.scrollTop;
alert('scrollHeight==>' + curWindow.document.body.scrollHeight);

    while(curWindow.document.body.scrollHeight > curWindow.document.body.scrollTop) {
      scrollTop = curWindow.document.body.scrollTop;
      if(scrollTop == 0) { 
        if(window.pageYOffset) { //firefox
          alert('firefox'); 
          scrollTop = window.pageYOffset; 
        } 
        else { //IE
          alert('IE'); 
          scrollTop = (curWindow.document.body.parentElement) ? curWindow.document.body.parentElement.scrollTop : 0; 
        } 
      } //end outer if
      alert('current scrollTop ==> ' + scrollTop);
      alert('take a shot here'); 
      selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().scrollBy(0,200);

    } //end while
```

Comment: I realize most of the solutions are jQuery based, but you still may be able to get help from them if you are looking for an "infinite scroll" effect: http://www.google.com/search?q=infinite+scroll Wish you luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you tell an element to scroll, if its `scrollTop` (or whatever appropriate property) doesn't change, then can't you assume that it has scrolled as far as is capable?

So you can keep track of the old `scrollTop`, tell it to scroll some, and then check to see if it really did it:

```
function scroller() {
    var old = someElem.scrollTop;
    someElem.scrollTop += 200;
    if (someElem.scrollTop > old) {
        // we still have some scrolling to do...
    } else {
        // we have reached rock bottom
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I just read through the jQuery source code, and it looks like you'll need the "pageYOffset". Then you can get the window height and document height.

Something like this:

`var yLeftToGo = document.height - (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight);`

If yLeftToGo is 0, then you're at the bottom. At least that's the general idea.

Comment: Note, this doesn't work so well for IE. I think in IE you can do document.body.scrollTop or something. window.pageYOffset works in IE9 if you don't care about old browsers.

Comment: Yeah I figured depending on browser, they use different property name.

Comment: But apparently IE isn't as accurate as real browsers. =D

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to check if you reached the bottom of the page is this:

1. Get `document.body.clientHeight` = the height of the ACTUAL screen shown
2. Get `document.body.offsetHeight` or document.body.scrollHeight = the height of the entire page shown
3. Check if `document.body.scrollTop` = `document.body.scrollHeight - document.body.clientHeight`

If 3 is true, you reached the bottom of the page

Comment: `window.innerHeight` instead of `document.body.clientHeight`

Answer (score 4):

```
function scrollHandler(theElement){
   if((theElement.scrollHeight - theElement.scrollTop) + "px" == theElement.style.height)
       alert("Bottom");
}
```

For the HTML element (like div) add the event -- onscroll='scrollHandler(this)'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I've used to power infinite scrolling list views:

```
var isBelowBuffer = false;  // Flag to prevent actions from firing multiple times

$(window).scroll(function() {
    // Anytime user scrolls to the bottom
    if (isScrolledToBottom(30) === true) {
        if (isBelowBuffer === false) {
            // ... do something
        }
        isBelowBuffer = true;
    } else {
        isBelowBuffer = false;
    }
});

function isScrolledToBottom(buffer) {
    var pageHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
    // NOTE:  IE and the other browsers handle scrollTop and pageYOffset differently
    var pagePosition = document.body.offsetHeight + Math.max(parseInt(document.body.scrollTop), parseInt(window.pageYOffset - 1));
    buffer = buffer || 0;
    console.log(pagePosition + "px / " + (pageHeight) + "px");
    return pagePosition >= (pageHeight - buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="add"></add>

<script>
    window.onscroll = scroll;

    function scroll () {
    if (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight >= document.body.scrollHeight - 100) {
            document.getElementById("add").innerHTML += 'test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />';
        }
    }
</script>
```