# How to show a div when the user scrolls to the end of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://codepen.io/BrianDGLS/pen/yNBrgR

This is what I am currently using which allows the user to track where he is on the page.

What would I have to do to show a div when the user reaches the bottom of the page? And continue to show it until he hits refresh

#show {display: none}

```
<div id="show">
<p>Hello</p>
<p>World!</p>
</div>
```

Show the div '#show' when the user reaches the bottom of the page and continue to show it for as long as he stays on the page.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059888/detect-when-scroll-reaches-the-bottom-of-the-page-without-jquery

Comment: scrolled to bottom:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom
im curious if you can persist the div with only client side (you can do it with cookies I'm guessing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a convention that mirrors the sample JS code:

```
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(),
            docheight = $(document).height(),
            winheight = $(window).height(),
            scrolled = (wintop / (docheight - winheight)) * 100;

          if (scrolled >= 100) {
            $(yourDiv).show();
          }
        });
```

The computation of the scroll percentage is straight from the [link](http://codepen.io/BrianDGLS/pen/yNBrgR) you provided and the condition just checks if you've reached 100% of the page (minus current window size).

You could also change 100 to be whatever percentage if you want to load the div before the user reaches the absolute bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var op = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if( op >= $(document).height() ) $("#show").show();
});
```

Comment: The bottom of the page is not `100`, this wouldn't work as expected.

Comment: `$(window).height()` does not result in the height of the document. `$(document).height()` does.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I answered too fast. @arcyqwerty has a good answer. Anyway I'll change mine. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger a Javascript function when the `<div id="show">` is visible in the client's viewport, for that you can [use a plugin](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear)

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
var show=false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() || show==false) {
       $("#show").show();
       show=true;
   }
});
```