# jquery auto load more not working on ie 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

i am using this code in my html page for loading more data when user scroll to the bottom of page.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
```

i have also tried this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight() == $(document).innerHeight())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
```

i don't now what is wrong with ie8 but it dose not work on it. is there any way to make it run?

**update**
seems like problem was from .scrolltop() i find a code on the web and replace it like this:

```
var sTop = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset || 0;
if(sTop + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
```

it worked, but i have no idea about the first line and just copied it.is this standard? can it be used?

Comment: IE8?  Are you serious?  I'm so sorry, bro :-(

Comment: Do you really need to support IE8? Microsoft will stop supporting IE8 on January 12, 2016. Most web developers no longer support IE8 unless it's required for some specific reason.

Comment: I know you're using jQuery, but maybe the answers in this question can point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10059888

Comment: Did you debug and see what is wrong? `console.log($(window).scrollTop(), $(window).height(), $(document).height());`

Comment: thank guys but i need the code work with IE8.

Comment: I'm sure your top line would work in *real* web browsers.  IE 8 is too old and too standards non-compliant.