# Stop Javascript .scrollBottom function

Tags: javascript, scroll

My .scrollBottom button works, but once it auto scrolls to the bottom I can't manually scroll back up because it is active and constantly scrolling down. What does it need for it scroll to absolute bottom and then STOP?

JavaScript

```
var timeOut;
  function scrollToBottom() {
    if (document.body.scrollBottom!=0 || document.documentElement.scrollBottom!=0){
    window.scrollBy(0,20);
    timeOut=setTimeout('scrollToBottom()',10);
    }
  else clearTimeout(timeOut);
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="scrollToBottom();return false">BUTTON</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div might help with scrolling to the bottom.

Comment: Try `console.log(document.body.scrollBottom,document.documentElement.scrollBottom);` at the top of `scrollToBottom`. You will then see why your function always passes the conditional. [See this thread for your answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148701/how-to-determine-if-vertical-scroll-bar-has-reached-the-bottom-of-the-web-page/13526491#13526491)

Comment: Please don't pass strings to `setTimeout`!  That uses `eval` (which is bad).  Pass functions: `timeOut=setTimeout(scrollToBottom, 10);`  or `timeOut=setTimeout(function(){ scrollToBottom() },10);`

Answer (score 0):

I found that by removing the `timeOut=setTimeout('scrollToBottom()',10);`
the button scrolls down by 20 pixels on press.
With that information - I changed the `window.scrollBy(0,20);` to a ridiculous number like: `window.scrollBy(0,2000000);`
so I got this code:

```js
var timeOut;
  function scrollToBottom() {
    document.body.scrollBottom!=0 || document.documentElement.scrollBottom!=0
    window.scrollBy(0,2000000);
}
```

And paired with

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

It does the trick :)