# How to determine if the bottom of a website was reached on iPhone browser?

Tags: javascript, iphone, scroll

If an iPhone user scrolls vertically down to the bottom of a site, I need to know this (via JavaScript event).

I already checked on this [How do you know the scroll bar has reached bottom of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060389/how-do-you-know-the-scroll-bar-has-reached-bottom-of-a-page) and this solution seems to work well on desktop browsers (tested on Google Chrome).

On iPhone though it won't work.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: @Sebas I don't know. If I use the code proposed in the link above that I posted, the function foo() simply won't get called (on iPhone at least): `$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
foo();
}
});`

Comment: did you check this? http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6724

Comment: @Seba That's it! Using the workaround posted in that link did the trick. If you want you can post your answer as a reply here and I'll mark it as the right answer.

Comment: ok! thanks, i'm doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is due to this JQuery deffect, did you check this?

[bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6724](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6724)

They provide a workaround.

rgds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jquery plugin called iosScript Refer to [this](https://github.com/iosscripts/iosSlider) location for more details.