# Display div when at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now i have made the footer to appear when i scroll up and hide when i scroll down.
How do i make it appear when i am at the bottom of page?

https://jsfiddle.net/48az3u64/

```
// Hide Footer on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){

        $('footer').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    } else {

        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('footer').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show div when user reach bottom of the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768264/how-to-show-div-when-user-reach-bottom-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/48az3u64/9/

I only added a function IsBottom() found from this post [How do you know the scroll bar has reached bottom of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060389/how-do-you-know-the-scroll-bar-has-reached-bottom-of-a-page#answer-5060440)

```
function IsBottom() {
    return $(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height());
}
```

to add your nav-up class back when you scroll, and to disable your timer.

I strongly suggest not to use a timer for this kind of thing, since you are processing your function every quarter of seconds even if there haven't been any scroll. You should probably just call your hasScrolled() directly in the scroll event and use a debounce function to not fire it too much. Here is a link for more info on debounce

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function