# How to get alert when user reaches the bottom of a page which is opened in bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have written a script which works for the html and body section. But this script does not work for the modal when it is opened.

SCRIPT

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('body').height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
       $zopim(function() {
                $zopim.livechat.button.hide();
        });
        $('.zopim').css('display','none');
//                        alert('Bottom reached!');
    }
    else{
            $zopim(function() {
                    $zopim.livechat.button.show();                  
            });
    }
});
```

This on scroll functionality works properly. I want the same thing to happen for the modal content

```
<div id="buildingModal" class="modal fade closeModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:100%;margin: 0px auto;">
           <!-- Modal content-->
           <div class="modal-content">  
             <div class="modal-body modalIframe">
               <iframe id="iframe" src="abc.php" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you know the scroll bar has reached bottom of a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060389/how-do-you-know-the-scroll-bar-has-reached-bottom-of-a-page)

Comment: @Manish My question is how do we know scroll bar has reached bottom of modal.

Comment: u saw the above link?

Comment: Yes I saw the above link. In that example, the <iframe> doesn't open in a modal.